# Connecting User Model To two Databases In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, orm, model, multiple-databases

In my rails 6 application, I have to connect User model to two database conditionally. So on some condition I have to fetch record from users table in Database 1 and on some conditions I have to fetch records from users table in Database 2.

Is it possible to configure two different database in model level?

Answer (score 0):

Rails supports connections to multiple databases, but you'll have to configure them above the model level.

Have a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html and more specifically at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#granular-database-connection-switching